# Android RFID reader integrated

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I'm guessing not, but just in case, are there any Android devices enabled for reading RFID microchips with no need of external hardware?

Comment: Yes. NFC tags are based on the already existed RFID tags (e.g. Mifare Classic) so it is possible to read RFID chips with a NFC reader. Ofcourse not every RFID chip can be read with a NFC reader. What kind of RFID chip do you want to read?

Comment: Thanks @S.Pols. I'm trying to read pets microchips, which apparently I cannot :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, RFID is a form of NFC. Check out this [list for devices supporting NFC](http://www.nfcworld.com/nfc-phones-list/) or the similar [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NFC-enabled_mobile_devices).

Comment: Thanks @mach. I'm trying to read a RFID dog chip from Android "NFC Tools" app, with no success. Any tip on the right direction to start writing my own RFID reader test?

Comment: There are several standards for RFID, Animal tags often use the unregulated 120–150 kHz range and are not supported by Android handsets (what I know of)

Comment: I guess you would need some sort of scanner like this one:http://skyrfid.com/Readers_LF_125.php#Bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

Not commercial handsets available at major retailers, but certainly on the Enterprise side and in multiple band channels depending on the need.

Some RFID (not NFC) tags can be emulated and read by the NFC interface on the device, it just has to match the spectrum and not be one with a particularly large or complicated memory. See Here: http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/hacking-rfid-payment-cards-made-possible-with-android-app/

You might be best served by using a commercial USB reader and USB host adapter on many regularly available devices. Most of those actually communicate with USB serial, which is supported in teh kernel on most popular phones or tablets as long as it uses the FT232RL or PL203 USB Serial adapter chipsets. It will show up as the /dev/USBtty0 interface on the phone or tablet of choice.

Are you looking for other, specific capabilities as well?

Comment: Thanks @childofthehorn. Actually, the idea for the project is an app to enable users to read rfid just with their handsets, which it seems it's not possible :(

Comment: @ssantos This is the case. NFC != RFID directly and there are too many specs in RFID to be able to cover one device. In fact, the RFIDer is the first to cover the most popular spectrums and still hasn't been shipped.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. NFC works only on the 13.56MHz frequenty. Good luck with your project.